# IEC958 suspends instead of idle when there are no sound

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I use the built in digital audio of my motherboard connected to a surround system through an optical S/PDIF cable. By default, PCM stereo is available, which I use and it's working most of the time.

The problem is with the PCM stereo, that the sound server seems to be suspendeding immediately when no sound is playing. And when there is sound, it turns on late, hence the beginning of the sound sample is cut off. For example, the drum roll at system startup can be barely heard at all.

This also means that playing games with sound effects only sounds odd because the samples are heavily cut off. If there is a constant sound source, even from an another application, then the sound effects play normally.

The AC-3 surround mode (which I've also installed but rarely use) doesn't have this problems, it's always idle instead of suspended when there is no sound.

How do I configure IEC958 in PCM stereo mode so that don't suspend?

Edit: I've tried to remedy it by commenting out the `load-module module-suspend-on-idle` line in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` but it didn't work.

Comment: I have trouble reading it.... I'll edit it.

Comment: What part of my text you don't understand?

Comment: Well are there parts that you can get rid of? It is a bit long.

Comment: Well, the problem is with PCM stereo, that the data stream turns off when there is no sound playing, including completely silent part of videos/songs, and when something short plays, the beginning of it doesn't play cause either the stream from pulse or the receiver turns on late.